# Weakened presuppositions of the strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, law-of-large-numbers

Is there some version of the strong law of large numbers which only requires **pairwise** independent random variables, does **not** suppose identical distributions for them, but guarantees the convergence a. s. as customary?

**EDIT:** Posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355144/weakened-presuppositions-of-the-strong-law-of-large-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

$X_n=n$ is an example of a sequence of independent random variables for which $\frac  1n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k \to \infty$ alomost surely.